# How to open view page in popup in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have to open view page contain in popup instead of page.After click on view open view contain in popup[image] yii2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this code for opening popup. and also you need to render with ajax view using this `$this->renderAjax()`.

**controller**

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
       ...................
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                 return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url , ['class' => 'view', 'data-pjax' => '0']);
                            },
            ],
 ....................
 ]); 

$this->registerJs(
  "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {  // 'pjax:success' use if you have used pjax
    $('.view').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();      
       $('#pModal').modal('show')
                  .find('.modal-content')
                  .load($(this).attr('href'));  
   });
});
");

 yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'id'=>'pModal',
]);
 yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this one working but how to cancel this popup and data id not display proper format

Comment: put following code for close popup    `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"><?= Yii::t('comm', 'Close') ?></span>
   </button>`

Comment: jQuery.load() loads the entire web page (with header and footer). In this way you need to create a special layout for this view in order to load like a partial render.

Comment: See property for header and footer on ` yii\bootstrap\Modal` for more info. @DanA.S.

Comment: I was talking about the header and footer of the main layout of the web page that is loaded together with the body with $.load ()