# Yii2 load view in modal from doesn't work properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I am trying to load my view in modal form on `a` tag click. But for my misfortune the modal form stays empty. I am working on Yii2 MVC framework. Is it possible to do it in the way I am trying it or i am going in a deaf street? What i wrote so far is:
Controller action:

```
public function actionInquiry(){
        $model = new Inquiry();
        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $product = Product::findOne($id);

        return $this->render('inquiry', [
            'model' => $model,
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }
```

Part of the first view, where the button for the modal form is:

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="lineheight32">
                                                        <a class="btn-bg modalButton" href="/'.$lang->url.'/'.$inquiryPage->url.'?id='.$product->id.'">'.Yii::t('app', 'app.Make inquiry').'</a>
                                                    </div>';
                                                    \yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
                                                            'id' => 'modal',
                                                            'size' => 'modal-lg'
                                                    ]);
                                                    echo '<div id="modalContent>"></div>';
                                                    \yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
                                            echo '<div>
```

My view, which suppose to be loaded in the modal window:

```
<?php

use kartik\file\FileInput;
use kartik\helpers\Html;

?>
<div id="inquiry-page">
    <div class="height50"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h2 class="text-center"><span class="inquiry-heading"><?= Yii::t('app', 'app.Inquiry') ?></span></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 height50"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                    <img src="<?= $product->getProductImg() ?>" alt="<?= $product->title ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 grey-bg right-part-inquiry">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="x-mark">
                        <a href=""><img src="<?= Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl ?>/images/delete-icon.png" alt="delete"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 height50"></div>
                <?php $form = \kartik\form\ActiveForm::begin([
                        'method' => 'post',
                        'fieldConfig' => [
                        ]
                ]) ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'product_name')->textInput(['value' => $product->title ]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'surname')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'company')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'vat_number')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput() ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 padding0">
                            <?php
                            echo $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                                'options' => [
                                    'multiple' => false,
                                    'disabled' => (Yii::$app->params['numberPubPhotos'] == 0) ? true : false,
                                ],
                                'pluginOptions' => [
                                    'allowedFileExtensions'=> Yii::$app->params['allowedProductFileExtensions'],
                                    'maxFileCount' => Yii::$app->params['numberPubPhotos'],
                                ],
                            ]);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 padding0"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textarea(['rows' => 5]) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php \kartik\form\ActiveForm::end() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally my js:

```
$(function () {
        $('.modalButton').on('click', function () {
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data);
            });        
        });
    });
```

Comment: [This will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351792/how-to-open-view-page-in-popup-in-yii2)

Answer (score 2):

You choose correct way, but I prorose you, to make some chage to refactor your code according to yii2 standards:

1) The are som specific method in controller, for your purpose: `renderAjax()`, so you action in controller will be:

```
public function actionInquiry(){
    //set response is json
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $model = new Inquiry();
    //use POST and default yii2 method for secure to get id
    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
    $product = Product::findOne($id);
    //use renderAjax for transfer to view your modal
    return $this->renderAjax('inquiry', [
        'model' => $model,
        'product' => $product
    ]);
}
```

2) Part of the first view, where the button for the modal form will be:

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
       echo '<div class="lineheight32">'
//Heare use yii\helpers\Html for best code style
//And data attribute from HTML5 for save data 
echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'app.Make inquiry'), "javascript:void(0);",
[
    'class' => "btn-bg modalButton", 
    "data-url" => "/$lang->url/$inquiryPage->url", 
    "data-product_id" => $product->id]);
echo '</div>';
\yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin(['id' => 'modal','size' => 'modal-lg']);
echo '<div id="modalContent>"></div>';
\yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
echo '</div>';
```

3) Modal view without changes.

4) And your js will be:

```
$(function () {
        $('.modalButton').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                data: {'id': $(this).data('product_id')},
                success: function (data) {  
 $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What i get from the ajax response is the whole html but it doesn't load in the modal.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand you, this is quedtion or problem?

Comment: Problem :) I mean this is what i should get right from the response, right ? But can't render it in the modal view. Maybe i can't explain it well, sorry about that :)

Comment: As i understand, correct abswer will be, that in response you will got html and js whitch you can just insert in modal, using .html() function, for more info pls see documentation, for method renderAjax

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
        return $this->render('inquiry', [
            'model' => $model,
            'product' => $product
        ]);
```

with

```
        return $this->renderAjax('inquiry', [
            'model' => $model,
            'product' => $product
        ]);
```